# Clean way to post users web page shares to Facebook page

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for a way to show Facebook engagement on from our website on our Facebook page. IE, when someone likes/shares etc. a page on the website, that that activity be reflected by our Facebook page in some way.

I was planning on using the graph API calls to do page updates, but the permissions are granted to users, not to the app itself, meaning this would only be possible for existing administrators, defeating the whole purpose (Perhaps a bit obvious in hindsight).

**Is there a good, clean way of posting page likes/shares of our web pages to our Facebook page feed?**

Notes:

- I'm working in PHP and/or client side JS
- A high volume of posts drowning our regular content is not likely at the moment, however, advice about how to manage such a beast in the long run might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and want to share content from Facebook into your Website, the behavior you mention used to exist via the [Activity Feed or Recommendations Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/deprecated). However, it has been deprecated since Graph API version 2.3.

If what you want is to update comments from people in your Website to your FB Page, you could implement something in your backend which listens to content uploaded and uses your Page Access Token to create custom stories using your user's data. As you mention, it won't happen in the name of people, but you could be creative and make the text narrate what people did on your website. Maybe even use OpenGraph for this.